Why Linux return strange result on mount of very old nfs2 share?
I have a directory shared with nfs2 from very old unix (Interactive unix 4.1.1)
the directory is mount correct from Interactive Unix client.
Trying with Linux I have this strange result
sudo mount -o sec=sys,proto=udp,vers=2 -vv 192.168.0.15:/var/public /mnt/hd/
mount.nfs: timeout set for Tue Nov  5 13:42:02 2024
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=sys,proto=udp,vers=2,port=2049,bsize=32768,wsize=32768,rsize=32768,ac,acl,retry=1,retrans=2,addr=192.168.0.15'
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=1, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.0.15 prog 100005 vers 1 prot UDP port 1079
192.168.0.15:/var/public on /mnt/hd type nfs (rw,sec=sys,proto=udp,vers=2,port=2049,bsize=32768,wsize=32768,rsize=32768,ac,acl,retry=1,retrans=2)

The share mount sucessfully but..
cd /mnt/hd/
ls
/bin/ls: cannot access 'share': Too many levels of symbolic links
share

I have tried also removing all options (ac, acl, port..)
but same result.
Is a bug of nfs? Or there is a solution?
On Linux client dmesg report
VFS: Lookup of 'share' in nfs 0:58 would have caused loop

The share "share" is a directory.

Can you check if share is a symbolic link that results in a loop? It might depend on the mount point or other file system contents if the link results in a loop or not.

No, is a directory.

This would be the time to start Wireshark and look at what your Linux client actually does, and what your UNIX server actually responds.

Too many levels of symbolic links
